# R: how to reorder legend key in ggplot2 line plot to match the final values in each series?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting line charts showing the change in price over time for multiple instruments, using ggplot2. I have succeeded in getting multiple lines on the plot and adding values showing the most recent change in price. What I want to do (and have not yet achieved) is to reorder the legend key so that the price series that has risen the most is at the top of the legend, followed by the key of the price series that rose second-most and so on.

In the plot below, the legend shows the key in alphabetical order. What I would like it to do is to show the legend key entries in the order DDD, AAA, CCC then BBB, which is the order of performance as of the most recent date. How can I do this?

[image: ggplo2 chart showing legend order]

Minimal-ish code follows.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(scales)
require(gridExtra)
require(lubridate)
require(reshape)

# create fake price data
set.seed(123)
monthsback <- 15
date <- as.Date(paste(year(now()), month(now()),"1", sep="-")) - months(monthsback)
mydf <- data.frame(mydate = seq(as.Date(date), by = "month", length.out = monthsback),
                      aaa = runif(monthsback, min = 600, max = 800),
                      bbb = runif(monthsback, min = 100, max = 200),
                      ccc = runif(monthsback, min = 1400, max = 2000),
                      ddd = runif(monthsback, min = 50, max = 120))

# function to calculate change
change_from_start <- function(x) {
   (x - x[1]) / x[1]
}

# for appropriate columns (i.e. not date), replace fake price data with change in price
mydf[, 2:5] <- lapply(mydf[, 2:5], function(myparam){change_from_start(myparam)})

# get most recent values and reshape
myvals <- mydf[mydf$mydate == mydf$mydate[nrow(mydf)],]
myvals <- melt(myvals, id = c('mydate'))

# plot multiple lines
p <- ggplot(data = mydf) +
    geom_line( aes(x = mydate, y = aaa, colour = "AAA"), size = 1) +
    geom_line( aes(x = mydate, y = bbb, colour = "BBB"), size = 1) +
    geom_line( aes(x = mydate, y = ccc, colour = "CCC"), size = 1) +
    geom_line( aes(x = mydate, y = ddd, colour = "DDD"), size = 1) +
    scale_colour_manual("", values = c("AAA" = "red", "BBB" = "black", "CCC" = "blue", "DDD" = "green")) +
    scale_y_continuous(label = percent_format()) +
    geom_text(data = myvals, aes(x = mydate + 30, y = value, label = sprintf("%+1.1f%%", myvals$value * 100)), size = 4, colour = "grey50") +
    opts(axis.title.y = theme_blank()) +
    opts()

# and output
print(p)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
mydf <- melt(mydf,id.var = 1)
mydf$variable <- factor(mydf$variable,levels = rev(myvals$variable[order(myvals$value)]),ordered = TRUE)

# plot multiple lines
p <- ggplot(data = mydf) +
    geom_line(aes(x = mydate,y = value,colour = variable,group = variable),size = 1) +
    scale_colour_manual("", values = c("aaa" = "red", "bbb" = "black", "ccc" = "blue", "ddd" = "green")) +
    scale_y_continuous(label = percent_format()) +
    geom_text(data = myvals, aes(x = mydate + 30, y = value, label = sprintf("%+1.1f%%", myvals$value * 100)), 
                size = 4, colour = "grey50") +
    opts(axis.title.y = theme_blank()) +
    opts()

# and output
print(p)
```

[image]

I melted your full data set to save you several lines for plotting code. The key, as usual, is to make sure the variable is an ordered factor.

To address the issue that arose in the comments, you can pass whatever labels you like to appear in the legend itself, as long as you get the order correct:

```
ggplot(data = mydf) +
    geom_line(aes(x = mydate,y = value,colour = variable,group = variable),size = 1) +
    scale_colour_manual("", values = c("aaa" = "red", "bbb" = "black", "ccc" = "blue", "ddd" = "green"),labels = c('Company D','Company A','Company C','Company B')) +
    scale_y_continuous(label = percent_format()) +
    geom_text(data = myvals, aes(x = mydate + 30, y = value, label = sprintf("%+1.1f%%", myvals$value * 100)), 
                size = 4, colour = "grey50") +
    opts(axis.title.y = theme_blank()) +
    opts()
```

[image]

**Note**: Since version 0.9.2 `opts` has been [replaced](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/theme.html) by `theme`, e.g.:

```
+ theme(axis.title.y = element_blank())
```

Comment: Perfect! Note that `ordered factor` is unnecessary. Order of the level is important but ggplot2 doesn't care about if the factor is ordered or not.

Comment: Good to know, @kohske, thanks! I guess I'm overly paranoid about other people's code deciding on their own ordering if the factor isn't ordered.

Comment: Thanks to joran for this - I was avoiding a melt for the main data frame but it's of no real consequence and as you point out saves a lot of boilerplate. I guess it would be possible to define the `values = c("aaa" = "red")` part separately using a list so that I don't have to delve inot the ggplot part of the code each time I want to make changes to the items I want to plot...? Thanks also to kohske for input.

Comment: @joran I have belatedly realised that this solution does not really do what I want, because although the variables (aaa, bbb, etc) are ordered by value and appear sorted in the legend key, the labels in the legend key (AAA, BBB, etc) are not used in the answer above. I did not explicitly state in the original question that I want to use these labels in the legend key rather than the column names. How should I go about this?

Comment: @SlowLearner Just change the column names from aaa,bbb, etc to AAA, BBB, etc.

Comment: @joran - understood, but sadly not that simple. The problem is that in the real-world application that this simplified example represents, the labels will be long, have multiple words and may sometimes not be in English, so using different (shorter) column names to the verbose labels is highly preferable. Perhaps difficult to achieve?

Comment: @SlowLearner Don't be so pessimistic! Use `labels = c('AAA','BBB','CCC','DDD')` in `scale_colour_manual`.

Comment: @joran - indeed, I have already tried `scale_colour_manual("", values=c('aaa'="red", 'bbb'="blue", 'ccc'="black"), labels=c("Company A","Company B", "Company C"))` but then the legend key is sorted in the order of the labels rather than in the order of the values and the colours are also wrongly allocated. For example, 'Company C' is -24.6% and should be black, but the legend shows 'Company B' in black. And so I come full circle.

Comment: @SlowLearner Pass the labels in the order you want them to appear.

Comment: @joran - OK, so the point would be to sort the labels in the same order as the values (as these will be changing multiple times in the script as it loops through sets of instruments). Gotcha, will have a think about it.

Answer (score 3):

try this

- guides(colour = guide_legend(reverse=T))

Answer (score 0):

I think there's an easier way.  Once you melt the dataframe, order it by date-value and use the values for the last date to create the legend.  Since you ordered by value, the legend will display the lines in the order corresponding to whichever way you ordered the value (max to min or min to max).  Code below.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(scales)
require(gridExtra)
require(lubridate)
require(reshape)

# create fake price data
set.seed(123)
monthsback <- 15
date <- as.Date(paste(year(now()), month(now()),"1", sep="-")) - months(monthsback)
mydf <- data.frame(mydate = seq(as.Date(date), by = "month", length.out = monthsback),
                      aaa = runif(monthsback, min = 600, max = 800),
                      bbb = runif(monthsback, min = 100, max = 200),
                      ccc = runif(monthsback, min = 1400, max = 2000),
                      ddd = runif(monthsback, min = 50, max = 120))

# function to calculate change
change_from_start <- function(x) {
   (x - x[1]) / x[1]
}

# for appropriate columns (i.e. not date), replace fake price data with change in price
mydf[, 2:5] <- lapply(mydf[, 2:5], function(myparam){change_from_start(myparam)})

mydf <- melt(mydf, id.var=1)

#Order by date and value.  Decreasing since want to order greatest to least
mydf <- mydf[order(mydf$mydate, mydf$value, decreasing = TRUE),]

#Create legend breaks and labels
legend_length <- length(unique(mydf$variable))
legend_breaks <- mydf$variable[1:legend_length]

#Pass order through scale_colour_discrete
ggplot(data=mydf) + geom_line(aes(x = mydate,y = value,colour = variable,group = variable),size = 1) + scale_colour_discrete(breaks=legend_breaks)
```