# edits in a ggplot2, geom = "line"

Tags: r, time, ggplot2, dashboard

I have a line plot of some event at a hospital that I have been struggling with.

The challenges that I haven't solved yet are, 1) sorting the lines on the plot so that the patient-lines are sorted by Assessment-date, 2) coloring the lines by the variable 'openCase' and finally, 3) I would like to remove the Discharge-point (the blue square) for the cases that are in the year 2014 (or at some other random cut of date).

Any help would be appreciated?

Here is my sample data,

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)

df <- data.frame(
 date = seq(Sys.Date(), len= 156, by="5 day")[sample(156, 78)],
 openCase = rep(0:1, 39),
 patients = factor(rep(1:26, 3), labels = LETTERS)
)

df <- ddply(df, "patients", mutate, visit = order(date))
df$visit <- as.factor(df$visit)
levels(df$visit) <- c("Assessment (1)", "Treatment (2)", "Discharge (3)")

qplot(date, patients, data = df, geom = "line") + 
geom_point(aes(colour = visit), size = 2, shape=0)
```

I'm aware that my example data is not perfect as some of the assessment datas is after the treatments and some of the discharge data is before the assessments data, but that part of the challenge that my base data is messed up.

What it looks like at the moment,
[image: draft client dashboard]

#### Update 2012-04-30 16:30:13 PDT

My data is delivered from a database and looks something like this,

```
df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(15965L, 15680L, 16135L, 15730L, 
15920L, 15705L, 16110L, 15530L, 15575L, 15905L, 16140L, 15795L, 
15955L, 15945L, 16205L, 15675L, 15525L, 15830L, 15625L, 15725L, 
15855L, 15840L, 15615L, 15500L, 15780L, 15765L, 15610L, 15690L, 
16080L, 15570L, 15685L, 16175L, 15740L, 15600L, 15985L, 15485L, 
15605L, 16115L, 15535L, 15755L, 16145L, 16040L, 15970L, 16000L, 
16075L, 15995L, 16010L, 15990L, 15665L, 15895L, 15865L, 16120L, 
15880L, 15930L, 16055L, 15820L, 15650L, 16155L, 15700L, 15640L, 
15505L, 15750L, 15800L, 15775L, 15825L, 15635L, 16150L, 15860L, 
16100L, 15475L, 16050L, 15785L, 15495L, 15810L, 15805L, 15490L, 
15460L, 16085L), class = "Date"), openCase = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), patients = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 26L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", 
"D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", 
"Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"), class = "factor"), 
    visit = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
    2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
    2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
    3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("zym", "xov", "poi"
    ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("date", "openCase", "patients", 
"visit"), row.names = c(NA, -78L), class = "data.frame")
```

The number of levels in `visit`, and specific labeling, will most likely change so I would like some kind of code where I `rank` or `sort` based on my existing data instead (`visit`) of generating new variables.

Comment: Two separate color mapping (lines and points) is going to be a challenge (in ggplot2) as it isn't really designed to allow you to do that.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean about your `visit` variable. You say "In my real data I am not creating the `visit` variable and can therefore not use the `rank` inside `ddply` as in the example above." Maybe it would help if you break out this part of the question, showing first (as a separate code block) something to create example data and then showing how you need that data transformed. Just going off what you have said, why not just assign the result of the `ddply` to some other variable than `visit` and use that?

Comment: @BrianDiggs, I've made a small update to my initial question. Please let me know if this answers your question. Thanks.

Comment: Now I'm confused too.  The answer I gave below only depends on the `rank(date)` stuff in order to construct the `Visit` variable in the first place; if you replace `df2` with `df` in the code below, you should get a fine plot -- the only thing missing is that the "Discharge" points aren't removed for certain cases, because there is no longer a "Discharge" point.  I guess I don't understand what the visit code represents -- can they really come in any order? Do you want the data sorted by (e.g.) date of `zym` regardless of whether it is the first, second, or third visit by an individual?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm still not sure I understand what is wrong with @Ben's answer, but I'll try adding one of my own.  Starting with the `df` given in the edit.

Create a new variable `Visit` (note the capital V) which is Assessment/Treatment/Discharge based on the ordering of the dates given.  This is @Ben's code, just re-written.

```
df <- ddply(df, "patients", mutate, 
  Visit = factor(rank(date),
                 levels = 1:3,
                 labels=c("Assessment (1)", "Treatment (2)", "Discharge (3)")))
```

I don't understand how this relates to the `visit` column in the data originally; in fact, the original `visit` column is not used hereafter:

```
> table(df$Visit, df$visit)

                 zym xov poi
  Assessment (1)  16   7   3
  Treatment (2)    3  16   7
  Discharge (3)    7   3  16
```

Reorder the patients (again copying Ben):

```
df$patients <- reorder(df$patients,df$date,function(x) min(as.numeric(x)))
```

Determine the subset of points that should be shown (same idea as Ben, but different code)

```
df2 <- df[!((df$Visit == "Discharge (3)") & (df$date > as.Date("2014-01-01"))),]
```

To add something new, here is a way to make the lines different colors without impacting the legend

```
ggplot(df, aes(date, patients)) +
    geom_blank() +
    geom_line(data = df[df$openCase == 0,], colour = "black") +
    geom_line(data = df[df$openCase == 1,], colour = "red") +
    geom_point(data = df2, aes(colour = Visit), size = 2, shape = 0)
```

[image]

Comment: I might have been the one who confused things, and I'm sorry for that.

I realized I needed to order my factor variable 'patients' using the data before melt, as the _ordering tool_, as explained in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10074483/r-how-to-reorder-legend-key-in-ggplot2-line-plot-to-match-the-final-values-in-e/10074684#10074684).

I'll award the bounty to Brian Diggs because he completed Ben's answer.

Thanks!

Comment: If anyone is interested to see exactly how I solved it please have a look at [this post, organize text on geom_point using geom_text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476630/organize-text-on-geom-point-using-geom-text). Thanks, Eric

Answer (score 7):

This is part-way:

Starting from after your initial definition of the data.

First, I think you want `rank(date)` rather than `order(date)` -- it made more sense to me, anyway.

```
df <- ddply(df, "patients", mutate, visit = rank(date))
df$visit <- as.factor(df$visit)
levels(df$visit) <- c("Assessment (1)", "Treatment (2)", "Discharge (3)")
```

Reorder patients by minimum date value (= Assessment date):

```
df$patients <- reorder(df$patients,df$date,function(x) min(as.numeric(x)))
```

Create a new data set missing the Discharge point, where they are after Jan 1 2014 (if you wanted to drop the Discharge point for cases that were *assessed* after a given date, you'd need to use `ddply`):

```
df2 <- subset(df,!(visit=="Discharge (3)" & date > as.Date("2014-01-01")))
```

As @Joran pointed out above it's a bit hard to get two separate colour scales for different variables, but this sort-of works (you have to make `openCase` into a factor in order to combine it with the colour scale for `visit`)

```
ggplot(df, aes(date, patients)) + geom_line(aes(colour=factor(openCase))) + 
    geom_point(data=df2,aes(colour = visit), size = 2, shape=0)
```

Alternately (and I think this is prettier anyway), you could code `openCase` with line type:

```
ggplot(df, aes(date, patients)) + geom_line(aes(linetype=factor(openCase))) + 
    geom_point(data=df2,aes(colour = visit), size = 2, shape=0)
```

[image]

Comment: I was thinking I'd recommend faceting on openCase, with nrow = 2 and scales = "free_y".

Comment: @joran, that is an interesting idea. Though I do not know how easy it would be to compare the two groups if the are on separate facets (the actual data have 150 subjects). I will try it out.

Comment: @BenBolker, is there a way I can `rank` the data if my data comes with the `visit` variable? In other words, In my real data I am not creating the `visit` variable and can therefore not use the `rank` inside `ddply` as in the example above.